# How do use regular expression replace remove the 0 start character?

Tags: javascript, regex

I use this code to replace not numeric character,but when the number is start with 0,like "000001111" or "0000000", 0 will appear in the front.

I want to replace the 0 start number,how to fix my code?
When all the input is 0,like this "00000000",keep only one 0,when input number like this "000234",keep 234.

My code:

```
<input id="text_target_value" maxlength="11" class="text-right number" type="text" onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[^\d]/g,'')";">
```

I only want to fix onkeyup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try alternating between your `[^\d]` and

```
^0+(?!$)
```

That will match leading zeros, but not the final zero, in case the string is composed of all zeros. Also, better to attach handlers properly using Javascript rather than using inline attributes:

```js
document.querySelector('#text_target_value').onkeyup = function() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d]+|^0+(?!$)/g, '');
}
```

```html
<input id="text_target_value" maxlength="11" class="text-right number" type="text">
```

Comment: Sir,I must input a integer,not allow decimal,so how to modify?

Comment: No modifications needed, because the initial `[^\d]+` will already strip out periods.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need regular expression. just use `Number` function like in the below example;

```js
function relpacing($this) {
  $this.value = Number($this.value);
}
```

```html
<input id="text_target_value" maxlength="11" class="text-right number" type="number" onkeyup="relpacing(this)">
```

Comment: Don't forget `type="number"` to accept only Numbers